# ASP.NET AJAX, page constantly not found

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I've been requested a webservice in my company, and I've been obligated to use ASP.NET to develop it, which I don't know much, and I don't properly like. The thing is, I have most of the service developed (the front end), and I'm now ready to pull data from the server, but I can't seem to do it using AJAX. I've tried literally tens of combinations/classes/voodoos and nothing. Right now, the JavaScript request snippet is like this:

```
var request = null;
request = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (request != null) {
    request.onreadystatechange = state_Change;
    request.open("post", "Scripts/CSharp.aspx/GetTime?=true", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send();
}
else { alert("Error on request"); }
function state_Change() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
        else { alert("Error on XML"); }
    }

}
```

And the CSharp.aspx.cs is like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);     
    if (Request.QueryString["GetTime"] == "true")
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
}
```

I've used lots of other stuff like:

```
namespace ReportWebPortal
{
public class WebService1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace ReportWebPortal
{    
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and some other. I'm now at the peak of desperation, as I have absolutely no idea what to do. I've seen loads of pages explaining ASP.NET AJAX to no avail.

BTW, currently it just is one page with some menus that works mostly with Javascript, using little of the ASP.NET capabilities.

EDIT: Forgot error output

It just says that the file is not found
Scripts/CSharp.aspx not found

Comment: You need to describe the problem in more detail. What happens when you try the code? Do you see any of the alerts? Are there errors in the [console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)?

Comment: Sorry forgot that, already edited. Basically it says the file is not found.

Comment: What happens if you use `http://www.yoursite.com/CurrentDir/Scripts/CSharp.aspx` as the address in the browser? (substituting the appropriate values)

Comment: Just added "http://localhost:53274/Scripts/CSharp.aspx", but the error is still the same.

Comment: and your CSharp.aspx resides in a Scripts folder in the root of the web site? (don't speculate but verify :) )

Comment: Any reasons your not using jquery for the ajax part?

Comment: Well, if it says file not found then the path is incorrect. Note that you've given it a relative path so if the page that does the Ajax call is on localhost:53274/whatever/foo.aspx then it tries to fetch localhost:53274/whatever/Scripts/CSharp.aspx. Try to give it an absolute path (`/Scripts/CSharp.aspx`)  or (just to test it) the full url. The browser's dev tools should show the full path of the file it tries to fetch.

Comment: It's in the Scripts foldes, which is in the root folder (at least in the Visual Studio as is).

Comment: The CSharp.aspx doesn't exist in the server directory, just CSharp.aspx.cs, and I've tried making the call to this one. I don't anything about ASP.NET, but shouldn't the .aspx be generated in the compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
request.open("post", "Scripts/CSharp.aspx/GetTime?=true", true);
```

to

```
request.open("post", "Scripts/CSharp.aspx?GetTime=true", true);
```

Also, browse to this url to double check it works before trying AJAX

Comment: That didn't help. But I was enable server browsing, and entered the Scripts directory and this appeared:
CSharp.aspx.cs. Shouldn't the CSharp.aspx be generated in the compile time?

Comment: the aspx.designer.cs file is generated when you modify the .aspx page (design time). The aspx and aspx.cs page should be generate for you when you add a webform to your project. Before doing any AJAX calls I would make sure you can direct your browser to this page. If this does not work then you have other issues

Comment: Hum, didn't know that. I'm trying this call from a plain cshtml page. Is there a way to make this kind of calls from this? I would just like to have a server-like function running, answering this calls, I don't need anything fancy, but the lead programmer required me to do it in ASP.NET, even though I don't need any of it's functionalities.

Comment: Just take this 1 step at a time. Forget AJAX for a moment. Can you direct your browser to "YOUR_SITE/scripts/csharp.aspx?gettime=true" ? What happens when you do this?

Comment: Yeah, I createed a webform with the CSharp.aspx.cs in it, and I can now make direct linking to the service (with AJAX working already xD).

Comment: I'm gonna change my framework to djangoo, I'm tired of the asp.net. But at least I was able to find the problem. Thanks